# XSS Sanitization of RSS Feeds using JS

Tags: javascript, html, security, rss

I need to pull an rss feed with links, headlines, and descriptions onto the front page of a website, and while I would like to think the source is trustworthy, you can never rule out malicious actors. I also would like to avoid iframes, since a sufficiently secure iframe sandbox would impact the browsing experience, and make the snippets less useful.

This is the parser/sanitizer I am testing, which relies on the built-in DOMParser (not regex ;) ) and I would love to know, not if the code is elegant, it isn't, but if it's reasonably xss safe. Tidying can come later. I've included a base test case, and a couple of test cases with a few simple xss exploits coded in. Run in Firefox Dev Edition 45 and Chrome 47, it catches what's there quite handily.

```
// Factory that returns an object that exposes a few 
// crude ways to pull data from a feed
var extractor = function (rss) {
  return {
    parser: new DOMParser(),
    // Parse items only when requested.
    get items () {
      if (!this._rawItems) {
        this._rawItems = this.parser.parseFromString(rss, 'application/xml').querySelectorAll("item");
      }
      return this._rawItems;
    },
    // Pull out one parsed item.
    item: function (index) {
      return this.items[index];
    },
    // Pull out the description. Parse to HTML without loading anything
    // to DOM then pull out text content, avoids several exploits.
    description: function(index) {
      return (
        this.parser
        .parseFromString(this.item(index).querySelector("description").textContent, "text/html")
        .body
        .textContent
      )
    },
    // Just extract title text. No contained html ever gets parsed.
    title: function(index) {
      return this.item(index).querySelector("title").textContent;
    },
    // Whitelist http and https protocols. Anything else is wiped
    url: function(index) {
      var url = this.item(index).querySelector("link").textContent;
      var protocol = url.split(':')[0];
      if (protocol === "http" || protocol === "https") return url;
      return ""
    }

  }
}

/* Test case follows: */

// Simple display builder, this represents the main use case, 
// Making sure to use safer DOM methods to construct, don't allow
// the live DOM to even touch the text strings.
// The only danger I can see is in the a href, which has already been
// whitelisted, but I'd love to know about any holes.
var makeHeadline = function(title, desc, url){
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  var h2 = document.createElement('h2');
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  a.setAttribute('href', url);
  h2.textContent = title;
  p.textContent = desc;
  a.appendChild(h2);
  a.appendChild(p);
  return a;
}

// Test data, template string for convenience, not production;
var feed = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
  <title>RSS Title</title>
  <description>This is an example of an RSS feed</description>
  <link>http://www.example.com/main.html</link>
  <lastBuildDate>Mon, 06 Sep 2010 00:01:00 +0000 </lastBuildDate>
  <pubDate>Sun, 06 Sep 2009 16:20:00 +0000</pubDate>
  <ttl>1800</ttl>

  <item>
    <title>Example entry</title>
    <description>Here is some text containing an interesting description.</description>
    <link>http://www.example.com/blog/post/1</link>
    <guid isPermaLink="true">7bd204c6-1655-4c27-aeee-53f933c5395f</guid>
    <pubDate>Sun, 06 Sep 2009 16:20:00 +0000</pubDate>
  </item>

  <item>
    <title>
      <![CDATA[Another Example Entry]]>
    </title>
    <description><![CDATA[<p>This is a big html section</p><script>alert('it contains dangerous scripts')</script><img alt="<script>alert('and nasty tricks')</script>" src="bogus" onerror="alert('that could ruin your day')">]]></description>
    <link>javascript:alert('and a horrible js url')</link>
    <guid isPermaLink="true">7bd204c6-1655-4c27-aeee-53f933c5395f</guid>
    <pubDate>Sun, 06 Sep 2009 16:20:00 +0000</pubDate>
  </item>

  <item>
    <title>Just another link test</title>
    <description><p>It's more innocent</p><div style="position:fixed; background: white; width: 100vw; height: 100vh; top:0; left:0;">... Maybe</div></description>
    <link>http://example.com" onclick="alert('the horror!')</link>
    <guid isPermaLink="true">7bd204c6-1655-4c27-aeee-53f933c5395f</guid>
    <pubDate>Sun, 06 Sep 2009 16:20:00 +0000</pubDate>
  </item>

</channel>
</rss>`

var parsedFeed = extractor(feed);
var headline1 = makeHeadline(parsedFeed.title(0), parsedFeed.description(0), parsedFeed.url(0));
var headline2 = makeHeadline(parsedFeed.title(1), parsedFeed.description(1), parsedFeed.url(1));
var headline3 = makeHeadline(parsedFeed.title(2), parsedFeed.description(2), parsedFeed.url(2));
document.body.appendChild(headline1);
document.body.appendChild(headline2);
document.body.appendChild(headline3);
```

Comment: [XSS prevention is a very broad topic](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Other_Cheatsheets). I would suggest using some existing XSS filtering library instead of rolling your own. I'm not even sure if this is suited for CodeReview or if it's more suited over at [Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/).